# Connecting LG 22MD4KA to 970A GAMING PRO CARBON Motherboard

Tags: multiple-monitors, monitor, 23.10, usb-c

I have a `LG 22MD4KA` monitor that connects only with USB-C. There *is* a UBS-C outlet in my mother board (`970A GAMING PRO CARBON` MSI) but I don't know if it can transmit an output. My current video card only has HDMI.

I have tried connecting the monitor but it does not see my computer. Is there a **way to program the USB-C a video output?**

Comment: Nope. HDMI or DP over USB-C is actually signals being set in the USB interface in the HDMI or DP protocol instead of the USB protocol. The signals are a function of the hardware, so if the USB interface hardware doesn't support it, you can't. No amount of kernel-side programming will change that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to https://forum-en.msi.com/index.php?threads/970-motherboard-usb-c-display.332978/ :

> Type C on 970 gaming pro carbon only supports file transfer but no video output